# use() statement on anonymous functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Is it a bad practice to use it?

Because people say that global variables are bad practice and the use thing brings variables from outside into the functions, so it's like global

This is how it looks

```
$a = 1;
$func = function() use($a){
  print $a;
};
```

Comment: No it isn't bad practise, in fact it's almost essential for callbacks from array_walk()/usort() etc which have fixed arguments and you need extra values feeding to the function

Comment: ^^ OR if possible I think even better would be to pass it as argument (Then you also have a few extra options like to make it optional and a default value)

Comment: However, the big difference between standard arguments passed to the function and "use" arguments is that standard arguments are the values available at the point when the function is called, whereas "use" arguments are the values at the point where the function is defined

Comment: @MarkBaker ^I think this is an answer worth? (I can imagine a few good examples to show these differences between use() and "normal arguments")

Comment: If you knew why globals are often a bad idea, you could just compare how these arguments apply to the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any arguments defined in the "use" arguments for an anonymous function use the value at the time when the anonymous function is defined; so they must exist at that point; but they don't need to be passed (or even exist in the caller scope) when the function is called.

```
function myFunctionCreator() {
    $a = 1; // Must exist for the `use` clause
    $func = function() use($a){
        echo $a, PHP_EOL;
    };
    return $func;
}

$myFunc = myFunctionCreator();
$a = 2;

$myFunc(); // echoes 1 (value of $a at the point where the function was created)
```

As you can see from the above example, `$a` has a value of `1` at the point where the function is defined, and even though a variable with the same name exists at the point when the function called, it is the original `$a` (with the value `1`) that is used in the function call.

---

Arguments defined in the main argument definition need not exist when the function is defined, but the values must be passed as arguments to the function at the point when it is called.

```
function myFunctionCreator() {
    $a = 1; // Need not exist, and will be ignored
    $func = function($a) {
        echo $a, PHP_EOL;
    };
    return $func;
}

$myFunc = myFunctionCreator();
$value = 2;

$myFunc($value);  // echoes 2 (value of $a explicitly passed to the function call
                  //           at the time it is executed)
```

So the behaviour of the two types is quite different, and their purpose when combined provides a degree of flexibility that is quite different

---

As Rizier123 has mentioned in his comment, arguments passed to an anonymous function as "standard" can have defaults, typehints, etc, whereas "use" arguments cannot.

```
function myFunctionCreator() {
    $func = function(array $dataset = [1,2,3]) {
        foreach($dataset as $value) {
            echo $value, PHP_EOL;
        }
    };
    return $func;
}

$myFunc = myFunctionCreator();
$value = ['a','b','c'];

$myFunc($value);
$myFunc();
$myFunc(['x','y','z']);
```

Or (as the third call shows, arguments can be passed directly.

Andy of these applied to a "use" argument will result in a parse error

Comment: ^ Very nice examples :) Exactly what I thought of. Maybe also worth to mention is that with a normal argument you can make it optional an define a default value, which you can't with `use()` e.g. `function xy($x = 4){}`;`use($x = 4)` <- the use won't work